# What am I missing in my Java blocks?

Tags: java, c++

Newbie here.  I have a program that extract prime numbers from numbers 1-100.  The code below compiles but gives a blank output when interpreted.

However, when I omit the pair of curly braces in the nested for-block (2nd for-block), it'll give the correct output.

I also tried this in C++ and the issue is the same.  Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

```
public class PrimeNumbers {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int i, j;

        for(i=2;i<=100;i++) {

            for(j=2;j<=(i/j);j++) {
                if ((i%j == 0)) {
                    break;
                }

                if(j > (i/j)) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }                               
         }
     }
}
```

And here's my code in C++, the issue is the same with the 2nd for-block

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, j;
    for(i=2;i<=100;i++) {
        for(j=2;j<=(i/j);j++) {
            if(!(i%j))
                break;
            if(j > (i/j))
                cout << i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you tried "this" in C++, then where's your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. Here how you can check for prime numbers between 2 and 100.

```
public class PrimeNumbers {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
                j=i;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            System.out.println(i + " is prime");
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your code, close the nested for loop before second if.
So edit your code as below:

```
public class PrimeNumbers {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {

        for (j = 2; j <= (i / j); j++) {
            if ((i % j == 0)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (j > (i / j)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So that's where I'm missing.  My 2nd If-block should belong to the 1st For-block.  Thanks, this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of your second for loop `for(j=2;j<=(i/j);j++)` conflicts with your second if statement `if(j > (i/j))`.  You're exiting the for loop when `j <=(i/j)` but you're only printing when `j > (i/j)`.  Given this you will never enter that if and never reach the `System.out.println`.